# Django ORM : How to use Counter with annotate

Tags: python, django, django-orm

## tltr

Considering a list of emails:

```
list = ['a@a.com', 'b@a.com', 'b@a.com', 'a@a.com', 'c@a.com', 'a@a.com']
```

Considering a queryset of Users using these emails, how can I use annotate to count the occurrences of the Users emails in this list?

If I try this:

```
users = User.objects.all()
users.values('email').annotate(email_in_list=Count('email))
```

the result is `1` for every users.
I expect these results for each user:

a@a.com - 3

b@a.com - 2

c@a.com - 1

## Initial Question

I want to see how many refered users does have a user:

```
refered_user = Profile.objects.filter(user__groups__name="Refered")
list = refered_user.values_list('referer_email')

# Getting all the referers who  actually had refered users
referer_users = Profile.objects.filter(user__groups__name="Referer", user__email__in=list)
```

Now how can I see how many refered users has a referer?

I have tried this without success:

```
counter = Counter(refered_user)
referer_users.values('user__email').annotate(refered_num=counter['user__email'])
```

As requested, here are the models :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    referer_email = models.CharField(verbose_name='Email Referer', max_length=99, blank=True)
```

## EDIT : Considering Count()

I have tried this:

```
referer_users.values('user__email').annotate(refered_num=count('user__email'))
```

But the value of `refered_num` is always equal to 1, which is logical, because in the `refered_num` query, we have only User objects with one email for each.

How can I count the occurrences of the referer email in the `refered_user` list and annotate it in my `referer_users` query?

Comment: can you please share your models?

Comment: I have edited my question including the model

Answer (score 2):

Well, you wouldn't do it with Counter, that's a Python class for counting distinct items in an existing Python collection. You need to use the Django `Count` function:

```
from django.db.models import Count
referer_users.values('email').annotate(refered_num=Count('email'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this on the first place, but refered_num was equal to 1 for every referer_users. Maybe should try this one more time.

Comment: Unfortunatly, it does not work. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Hello Daniel, I tried to reformulate my problem. I think I was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Count
referer_users = referer_users.order_by()
referer_users = referer_users.values('email')
referer_users = referer_users.annotate(refered_num=Count('email'))
```

I think you are adding `order_by('id')`, and that's why it is giving 1. When order is added it also added to `group by` fields.

Comment: I am not using `order_by()`